# why am I getting this exception while importing data from oracle to hdfs?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

Please help me understand/resolve this exception. I am trying to import table from Oracle to HDFS using sqoop-1.4.5.

I am using this command for importing:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@<IP address>:1521:xe  --username <username> -P--table <database name>.<table name> --columns "<column names>" --target-dir  <target directory path> -m 1
```

Generated Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTrackerInstrumentation.create(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTrackerInstrumentation; @5: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/lib/DefaultMetricsSystem' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsSystem'
    Current Frame:
    bci: @5
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker', 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker', 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf', 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/lib/DefaultMetricsSystem' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b b200 03b8 0004 b0                 

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:513)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:665)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.importTable(OracleManager.java:444)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```